# R - ggplot2 Newline character usable by parse(text=X)

Tags: r, parsing, text, ggplot2, newline

I am trying to insert a deliberate line break into the axis title of ggplot2.  As shown by the MWE below, I am using `parse(text=X)` to evaluate the possible `LaTeX` style inclusion of Greek characters and sub/super-scripts.  I have seen that that the labeler tool of ggpot2 and expression objects should be able to process a new line character such as `\n`.  But I am committed to using `parse(text=X)`.  I have had no success incorporating this in my x and y axis title strings however.

- In the hard-coded MWE I loose everything after the `\n`.
- When I import this as `*{"\n"}*` from an external table, I get the same behavior as `*`.

Which leads me to suspect that `parse(text=X)` doesn't support the new line symbol.  If this is the case, what is the appropriate way to insert a new line?

In the past I have been able to use `atop` but prefer to try and use something different this time because it leaves too much blank space between lines.  So alternatively, I would accept an answer that demonstrates how to customize the spacing of `atop`.

MWE:

```
library(ggplot2)
library("grid")

print("Program started")

gg <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut))
gg <- gg + geom_bar(position="dodge")
gg <- gg + labs(y=parse(text="ahhhh\nWe~are~here"), x=parse(text="ahhhh\nWe~are~here"),title="title")

gg <- gg + theme(
                legend.justification=c(0,1),
                legend.position=c(0,1),
                legend.title=element_blank(),
                plot.background=element_rect(fill="red")
);
gg <- gg + guides(fill=guide_legend(title.position="top"))

print(gg)

print("Program complete - a graph should be visible.")
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your text in additional single quotes inside double-quotes and you'll get two-line labels on axes.

`gg + labs(y=parse(text="'ahhhh\nWe~are~here'"), x=parse(text="'ahhhh\nWe~are~here'"),title="title")`

You can construct plotmath output with combinations of single-quoted strings and expressions with some limitations - for example that your single-quoted string can not end with `\n`
Check this code

```
parse(text = "'ahhhh\nWe' ~are%=>% bold(here[123])")      # it works
parse(text = "'ahhhh\n' We~are%=>% bold(here[123])")      # it throws an error
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am not sure If I designed a bad MWE, but when I compile your solution with the extra single quotes I loose the ability to parse spaces and other insertions such as super scripts.  Is this specific to the string literal the single quotes creates?  Thanks.